# Make [structure] a synonym of [structural]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[structure](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) - 19 questions, all of which seem...

[structural](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structural) - 261 questions

I can't think of a good reason to have two separate tags here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks. I've added the synonym. There were a few questions in the [structure](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) that were not about [structural](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structural). However, the ones I saw used it more as a meta tag that had no value.